# Is this nginx config for phoenix + websockets correct?

Tags: nginx, websocket, phoenix-framework

I'm seeing `socket.js:229 WebSocket connection to 'ws://sitename.io/socket/websocket?token=&vsn=2.0.0' failed:`  and wondering if it's because of nginx.

here's my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name sitename.io;

    location /socket/websocket/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/socket/websocket;
        }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The config here worked! It turns out I was missing some important bits.

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.1/phoenix_behind_proxy.html